# IBM Watson Assistant: Multi-workspace for Facebook page?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

We have integrated a Watson Assistant skill/workspace with Facebook page using Watson-provided integration approach from virtual Assistants tab.

We are able to get the response from single skill/workspace. Now we want to add another skill/workspace to the integration, but we are not able add it.

Please let us know how can we enable multiworkspace approach for FB integration using watson provided integrations.

Answer (score 2):

At this time, you can only have [one skill per assistant](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-assistant-add#assistant-add-rename). You can swap existing skills using the tool.

If you are using the [Watson Assistant API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs) (V1 only) from an application, then you have access to multiple workspaces / skills. See the [Botkit Middleware for Watson Assistant for an example of dynamically switching workspaces](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/botkit-middleware). It is based on the [Watson SDKs](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/).